# Link from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly i am a coding novice and am happy to work with CSS and HTML but Javascript is my down fall !  I have purchased and downloaded a user survey / feedback system called Visitor Code and am working with it fine.

However to link to the survey is asks you to embed with code into the HTML.  This creates a HTML ribbon on the page, when you click it opens a qlightwindow with the content.  See the script below.

```
<!-- VisitorVoice -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var _vvb = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.aplusinsurance.co.uk/surveyadmin';
            var formId = 'costco-travel-feedback';

            function loadVV() {
              var vvjs = document.createElement('script'); vvjs.type = 'text/javascript'; 
              vvjs.src = _vvb + '/code/'+ formId +'.js';   
              var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(vvjs, s);
            };

            if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('load', loadVV, false); 
            else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', loadVV);
            </script>
            <!-- VisitorVoice -->
```

My question is, and where i need help, is how do i create just a simple link to form that creates / provides the same actions ?

Comment: Just remove all the `if(windo... window.addEventList...` and add the following as the url for your link: `<a href="javascript:loadVV()">Link</a>`

Comment: You might be trying to do more that the plugin is capable of. Take a careful look through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply defer calling the function - currently it is bound to your `load` event, simply remove those lines and call your function either from the link, an `onclick` or use javascript to add an event listener:

```
<a href="javascript:loadVV()">Go to Survey</a>
<a href="#" onclick="loadVV(); return false;">Go to Survey</a>
```

Here's `addEventListener` (my preferred method):

```
<a href="#" id="vv-link">Go to Survey</a>


document.querySelector('#vv-link').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault() // prevent following the link in the a tag
    loadVV(); // execute the loadVV function
}, false);
```

Here's an example implementation (you should see it in your console, logging `adding VV`):

```js
var _vvb = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.aplusinsurance.co.uk/surveyadmin';
var formId = 'costco-travel-feedback';

function loadVV() {
    console.log('adding VV')
    var vvjs = document.createElement('script'); vvjs.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    vvjs.src = _vvb + '/code/'+ formId +'.js';   
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(vvjs, s);
};

//if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('load', loadVV, false); 
//else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', loadVV);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:loadVV()">A</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - i have tried the example and it loads the ribbon not the actual form in the lightbox / window ?

Comment: Ah well sorry about that - if you want to create your own link you will have to have a look into their documentation, as your question does not contain any code that I could use to help you with that.

Comment: No worries - thank you for your help anyway.  I thought it was me going mad ;-)